# Name and existence of functor or monad to chain and terminate sequence of operations

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, terminology, functor

I am looking at libraries such as [Folktale](http://folktalejs.org) and [monet.js](https://cwmyers.github.io/monet.js/), I like being able to chain operations with `map` without null-checking or `if` statements, using e.g. `Maybe`, `Either`, `Task`.

I am wondering whether a similar construct exists to solve the following problem:

- I have an initial input.
- I want to construct a chain of functions that operate on the input.
- Each function may or may not return a result.
- If a function does not return a result, call the next function in the chain.
- As soon as a function returns a result, ignore the rest of the functions in the chain (similarly to `map`ping a function on a `Maybe.Nothing`)
- Return the result.

In other words, I'm looking for something similar to `Maybe` which holds a value and maps a function on `Just` but ignores a function mapped on `Nothing`, and you can extract the value. I'm looking for something that holds an input and an initial `null` result. When you `map` a function, it runs the function on the input only if `result` is null. If the function returns a value, that becomes the result and any other functions that are mapped are ignored. Finally, you can extract the result.

In imperative programming, this might look like:

```
var result1 = function1(input);
if (result1) {
  return result1;
}
var result2 = function2(input);
if (result2) {
  return result2;
}
// and so on.
```

Instead, I'd like to construct something along the lines of

```
Something(input).map(function1).map(function2).result()
```

or

```
compose(result, map(compose(function2, function1))(Something(input))
```

Does such a construct exist? Does it have a name? Even if this doesn't exist and I could write it myself, I'm at a loss as to what to call it.

### Update

Following the solution by @Bergi I used `Maybe.orElse`. I wrote a little helper called `ShortCircuit`, which I am posting below in case anyone finds this useful.

```
import Maybe from "data.maybe";

const ShortCircuit = function(input, result) {
  this.input = input;
  this.result = result;
};

ShortCircuit.of = function(input, f) {
  return new ShortCircuit(input, Maybe.fromNullable(f(input)));
};

ShortCircuit.prototype.orElseMaybe = function(f) {
  return new ShortCircuit(this.input, this.result.orElse(() => Maybe.fromNullable(f(this.input))));
};

ShortCircuit.prototype.get = function() {
  return this.result.get();
};

export default ShortCircuit;
```

And here is how you use it:

```
const result = ShortCircuit.of(input, f1).orElseMaybe(f2).orElseMaybe(f3).get();
```

Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Comment: Could implement a queue ; or use `Promise`

Comment: [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) might help, instead of using `map`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as the [`Alternative` type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) in Haskell. I have not yet found<sup>1</sup> a JS library implementing it, though there is [support for it in PureScript](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-alternatives) and a [discussion about specifying it in FantasyLand](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/issues/117).

Regardless, I've found a function in Folktale that does exactly what you want: [Maybe's `orElse`](http://docs.folktalejs.org/en/latest/api/data/maybe/Maybe.html#Maybe.prototype.orElse). You'd use it like this:

```
Something(input).orElse(function1).orElse(function2).get() // `get` throws when all failed
```

Even better, `orElse` is available not only for `Maybe` but also on `Either`, `Validation` and `Task`!

The [`getOrElse` method](http://docs.folktalejs.org/en/latest/api/data/maybe/Maybe.html#Maybe.prototype.getOrElse), known as [`orElse` in Monet.js](https://cwmyers.github.io/monet.js/#orelse), is not really helpful as it wouldn't execute your "handlers" only in the case of a fail. You can implement your own `Alternative` though using the `cata` method.

<sub>1: Googling "JS alternative" is not really helpful either, even when you know the name :-)</sub>

---

Oh, and just in case you are using promises, there's always the [`.catch(…)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) which has broad (ES6-backed) support.

Comment: Nice, `orElse` looks like it could fit the bill. Let me experiment with it and I will come back to confirm. Thanks @Bergi! Appreciated!

Comment: `var toMaybe = function(f) { return function() { return Maybe.fromNullable(f()); } };`

`var result = Maybe.fromNullable(f1(input)).orElse(toMaybe(function() { return f2(input); })).orElse(toMaybe(function() { return f3(input); })).get();` do the trick. Looks nicer with ES6 arrow syntax. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi `alt` (fantasy-land or `<|>` in Haskell) of the `Maybe` instance and `orElse` have the same type signature but slightly different implementations in Haskell. I'd say they are the same, but apparently they aren't. How are they different?

Comment: @ftor I'm not sure where you found `orElse` in Haskell? If you refer to [this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.6/docs/src/Data-Generics-Aliases.html#orElse) from the `syb` package, that does indeed do the same as the [default `instance Alternative Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-707), it's just written differently.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, exactly that. I was just wondering why they don't reuse it. There is certainly a reason, but it is probably not important.

Comment: @ftor It's more likely that they just overlooked it. Or wanted a distinguishable name and a function specialised to `Maybe`.